# Nomen für kontrovers

Tags: word-choice

Beispielsatz:

> Wie kontrovers die politische Ideologie ist, wird durch xy deutlich.

Gesuchtes Nomen:

> Die " " der politischen Ideologie wird durch xy deutlich.

Mein erster Gedanke wäre die *Kontroversität* gewesen, was aber anscheinend eine völlig andere Baustelle ist. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontroversit%C3%A4t))

*Umstrittenheit* wäre eine mögliche Option, die es laut Duden aber gar nicht gibt. Zudem suche ich ein eher bildungssprachliches Wort.

Hat jemand eine Idee, welche Wörter hier passen könnten?

Comment: Ganz interessant: Bei einer Google-Suche nach *Kontroversiellität* gibt es tatsächlich ein Ergebnis - ein stenographisches Protokoll vom österreichischen Parlament.

Comment: So etwas wie *Meinungsbandbreite*?

Comment: Dein Originalsatz ist (leider) schon ziemlich sinnlos - Ideologien können nur kontrovers sein, wenn es mindestens zwei davon gibt - In deinem Satz kommt aber nur eine vor. *kontrovers* heisst *entgegengewandt*, und in deinem Satz ergibt sich automatisch die Frage "gegen was?"

Comment: @tofro *kontrovers* heißt mittlerweile auch 'umstritten' (s. etwa https://www.dwds.de/wb/kontrovers [2], auch wenn das nicht mit der wörtlichen lateinischen Bedeutung übereinstimmt, hat sich das Wort weiterentwickelt.

Comment: Wenn es unbedingt die neue Bedeutung von „kontrovers“ sein müsste, nähme ich „die kontroverse Natur“, also 2 Wörter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Zunächst zu Alternativen**

Dein Satz würde auch so gut klingen:

> Die **Strittigkeit** der politischen Ideologie wird durch xy deutlich.

**Bedeutung von *Kontroversität***

Was du da als Wikipedia-Fund anführst, ist eine sehr spezifische Verwendung von *Kontroversität*, wie sie offenbar an pädagogischen Hochschulen en vogue ist (geurteilt nach der Zahl der dazu im Internet kursierenden Publikationen).

In normaler, nicht einem spezifischen Hochschulfach entnommener Verwendung ist *Kontroversität* durchaus als das verständlich, was du darunter vermutetest: das *Kontroverssein*.

Spätestens die Kontroversität deiner eigenen Frage sollte dir den Hinweis geben, dass dieses Wort auch genau so verwendet werden kann.

**Etwas Empirie**

Selbst bei Tante Google findest du Stellen, wo in ordentlichen deutschen Texten das Wort *Kontroversität* im Sinne von *Kontroverssein* verwendet wird. Du musst dich allerdings durch die Schutthalde von Didaktikseminararbeiten hindurchwühlen, die mit ihrer Verwendung des Begriffes *Kontroversität* die Google-Suchergebnisse dominieren.

Hier sind Fundstellen "normaler" Kontroversität:

- https://www.jugendportal.at/youth-reporter-blog/die-kontroversit%C3%A4t-der-sch%C3%B6nheit
- https://www.medienobservationen.de/2009/habermann-battlestar-galactica-reloaded/

**Kontroversität und Umstrittenheit im Wörterbuch**

Zum Nichtaufgeführtsein von Wörtern in der von dir konsultierten Duden-Ausgabe: Dass ein Wort in einer Duden-Ausgabe nicht drinsteht, heißt ja nicht, dass man annehmen dürfte, dass es das Wort nicht gäbe. Erstens: Du hast garantiert nur einen Mini-Duden zur Hand. Zweitens: Selbst im größten Riesenduden steht nicht alles drin, was in der Welt verwendet wird.

Ich muss allerdings gestehen, dass zu meiner Überraschung auch in meinem mittelgroßen Duden Universalwörterbuch 8. Auflage auf 2132 Seiten weder *Kontroversität* noch *Umstrittenheit* aufgeführt sind.

[image]

Interessanterweise lernen wir bei dieser Gelegenheit ein anderes Wort, das wir vorher garantiert nicht kannten: Kontumaz. An der Seltenheit kann es also nicht liegen. Vielleicht lassen Wörterbuchautoren Wortbildungen, die sich von selbst erklären, aus Sparsamkeit weg. Die Suffixe *-heit* und *-tät* sind so universell in der Verwendung, dass man sie praktisch an jedes Adjektiv anhängen kann (die einen an lateinisch, die andere an germanisch wurzelnde). Die daraus entstehenden Nomen alle in ein Wörterbuch aufzunehmen, wäre eine Heidenarbeit ohne wirklichen Mehrwert. Allerdings finde ich in meinem Mittelduden dann eben doch *Verzagtheit* und *Gebrechlichkeit* verzeichnet, jeweils direkt nach *verzagt* und *gebrechlich*. (Tja, die Hinfälligkeit von Theorien...)

Interessant sind übrigens die Fälle, wo aus Adjektiv + Suffix ein Nomen wird, das eine andere Bedeutung trägt als die Summe seiner Teile nahelegen würde. So heißt

> Gelegenheit

das ja aus "gelegen" + -heit entstand, nicht mehr "Gelegensein" sondern hat durch vielfältigen Gebrauch eine andere Bedeutung angenommen. Sonst könnte man wohl sagen:

> Die *Gelegenheit Wiens an der Donau bot der Stadt vielfältige Gelegenheit zum Handel.

Comment: *Strittigkeit* ist sehr gut. *Umstrittenheit* würde wohl auch ganz gut passen.

Answer (score 1):

Als bildungssprachliche Nomen im Bedeutungsraum von »kontrovers« würden mir folgende einfallen:

> - [die] **Diskrepanz** [zwischen den Ideologien]
> - [die] **Dissonanz[en]** [zwischen den Ideologien]
> - [die] **Kakophonie** [der Ideologien] *(abwertend)*

Verwandt wären aber auch schlichtere Ausdrücke wie

> - [der] **Widerstreit** [der Ideologien]
> - [die] **Unverträglichkeit** [der Ideologien]
> - [die] **Konkurrenz** [der Ideologien]

Comment: Dan zweite Kasten scheint es mir besser zu treffen. Dass die Ideologien sich unterscheiden müssen, damit man darüber streitet, ist klar. Die reine Existenz verschiedener Ideologien löst nicht zwingend Streit aus.

Comment: @guidot: Stimmt, nicht zwingend, meines Wissens sage ich das aber auch nicht. Gemäß der Frageüberschrift liste ich Nomen für _»kontrovers«_ auf, das mit der Ideologie ist nur ein Beispiel.